# Field IS NULL in IIF()

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have two types, `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

`TypeA` has two Series - `Series1` and `Series2`

`TypeB` has one Series - `Series1`

Below is the query I managed to come up with:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    TypesTable
WHERE
    Series1 = 'A3bBa#$#0sB2'
AND
    Series2 = IIF(Type != 'TypeB', 'vH2f##gYtL&', NULL);
```

I am having problem with the `Series2 = IIF(...)` part

How can I tell my query that

if `Type = TypeA`, `Series2` is equal to given `Series2` value by user

if `Type = TypeB`, `Series2` is NULL

I am having a hard time with the `IIF` since if `Type == 'TypeB'` `Series2` should be `Series2 IS NULL` and not `Series2 = NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend condition check in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    TypesTable
WHERE
    Series1 = 'A3bBa#$#0sB2'
AND
    ((Type = 'TypeA' AND Series2 = 'vH2f##gYtL&') OR (Type = 'TypeB' AND Series2 IS NULL))
```